# MATLAB Remove Only Certain Zeros from Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have seen plenty of answers regarding how to remove leading and/or trailing zeros, and how to remove all zeros from a vector or matrix.  What I need to do, though, is only remove some of them.  I have two matrices, and I only want to remove the entries where both of them are zero.  They are two-dimensional x and y coordinates, solved using characteristics (I can give more detail if needed) and I just want to remove the values where both matrices contain zeros at the same indices.  I can easily convert the matrices into vectors and work with vectors, so any help in either case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you propose to remove elements from the middle of a 2D matrix?

Comment: That's the point of the question.  I'm solving dx/ds=u, dy/dx=v, dc/ds=-\theta g(c), and I'm using 2D interpolation so get u and v values along the parametrization, thus giving me subsequent x and y values using forward Euler.  The number of elements in the x and y vector change for each starting point, though.  Any extra space that is not assigned in a given row is just given a 0 value.  I want, though, c=2 at (x,y)=(0,0), whereas I will get a bunch of entries implying c(0,0)=0, so I want to remove the points where c(0,0)=0.  I'll try both methods below and see which one is best.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume you're using vectors called `X` and `Y` (of the same length), and you want to remove only those entries where both vectors are zero. Here's how (not tested):

```
% Find the indexes where either X or Y is different from zero
% (these are the indexes of the components we want to keep)
I = find(X~=0 | Y~=0);

% Select the desired components from X and Y
X=X(I);
Y=Y(I);
```

Edit: As Oli has pointed out below (and stefano explained further), you should use logical indexing for better performance.

Comment: Cleaner is: `I = (X == 0 & Y == 0); X(I) = []; Y(I) = [];`  i.e. using logical indexing.

Comment: @Oli: Honestly curious -- how is this cleaner, i.e. what are the advantages?

Comment: @MartinB - the main benefit is omitting the `find` function. This often makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: @MartinB - not only cleaner, but if you type X(find(Y==something)), the matlab editor suggests you to fix it by removing the 'find' function, with the message: "To improve performance, use logical indexing instead of FIND"

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone.  I've used what Oli suggested with logical indexing and it is fantastic.  Thanks a bunch.